# Defining nearest features within shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

In a shapefile I have around 17000 lines with different ID. I would like to give a same ID to the feature lines which are close to each other.
for example in the picture : ID 306 and 305 should have both same ID because they are very close to each other.

Is there any suggested tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

[image]

Comment: For every pair that you want to create, the two lines are the ones that are the closest to each other? Or is there a possibility that you want to merge a line with another one that is not the closest one? In addition, can you provide some information on your license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a small buffer around each line

dissolve buffers

use spatal join to give the attribute of the buffer containing neightbour lines to each pair of lines.